# What is it when someone from some group (ethnic, religious, disability, etc.) can automatically talk for others from it?

Tags: sociology, identity, politics, feminism, difference

Is there a term for being for and against the view that (only) someone from some group (ethnic, religious, disability, etc.) can automatically talk for others from it?

It's kind of a political and sociological question, so apologies in advance (though philosophers do talk about tolerance and, of course, socio-ethical questions like recuperation).

It seems fundamentally wrong to say that I, e.g. as a woman, can talk for other women merely because I really am a woman. In deed, many women may want someone that isn't a woman to talk for them. By 'talk for' I mean assume a role whereby I am privileged in understanding what it means to be e.g. a woman.

But then again, there probably are commonalities of experience. What is the word for this impasse?

Comment: i'm actually not a woman, but i'm illustrating the question in the most universal and understandable way i can

Comment: Maybe [Standpoint epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminism-epistemology/#standpoint) is what you’re looking for?

Comment: maybe, but if so they don't seem to recognize that it's an issue, at all @Eliran

Comment: Ingroup / outgroup.

Comment: I can not understand if you are asking what can empower an individual to speak for a group, in which case the answer is any of the usual mechanisms of [delegating authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation), or when an individual is generic enough for us to take their reporting as representative of the group, in which case the answer is proper [statistical sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)).